# Is Mybatis supported with Spring 4.x?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, mybatis, ibatis, spring-4

I tried mybatis-spring 1.2.2 with mybatis 3.2.5 and Spring version 4.1.0.Release and it appears like it is not supported.

mybatis-spring 1.2.2 spring contains `org.springframework.core.MethodParameter` class however, `getContainingClass()` is not present.

I am getting the exception:
`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.MethodParameter.getContainingClass()`

Any idea is I could use Mybatis with Spring 4x at all? (even ibatis seems to be unsupported)

Comment: Let us know what are the dependencies you are using

Comment: Spring 4.x dropped support for Ibatis.
You can find a solution for this issue in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353286/no-support-for-ibatis-in-spring4-2-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking in the `pom.xml` of the Spring MyBatis [here](https://github.com/mybatis/spring/blob/master/pom.xml) I can see that the project itself depends on Spring 3.2.9:

```
...
<spring.version>3.2.9.RELEASE</spring.version>
...
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

So, based on that I wouldn't be surprised if I would get an exception like the one you are getting in my project and I would have to say that "no", it's not supported.

Comment: The fact the ibatis/mybatis is not included in spring orm 4.0.6 release (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm/4.0.6.RELEASE) implied that they are not yet supported in spring 4.x ..... it does include hibernate, jdo and jpa though.

Comment: Spring ORM never supported MyBatis 3 in the first place. MyBatis Spring, which is the library that the question is referring to, is a different library made by the MyBatis team.

Answer (score 0):

We are using MyBatis v3.2.7 with Spring v4.0.6 and so far we have not seen any issues. Since Spring usually maintains the backward compatibility, it usually works.

However, I am not sure (as of this writing) if it is totally supported in Spring v4.1.x.