# No support for iBatis in Spring4.2.0

Tags: ibatis, spring-orm

There is no support for ibatis in Spring4.2.0. MY project is upgrading from Spring 3.2.4 to Spring 4.2. As i googled, i found spring4.2 integration  examples with mybatis but not with ibatis. 
Can somebody help me on how i can add ibatis support?

Answer (score 8):

iBATIS 2.x support was removed from Spring in version 4.0 but there is a workaround for that. See this post:

http://blog.mybatis.org/2015/11/spring-4-got-you-down-with-no-ibatis.html

Basically you just have to add this dependency to your project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis-2-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```